# Solr in Component Services shows paused and can't start on Windows

Tags: apache, service, solr, nssm

I followed every step, but I can start the solr service. It says 'paused.

https://www.norconex.com/how-to-run-solr5-as-a-service-on-windows/

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Can you start Solr manually by going to the working directory and entering the path to solr.cmd manually with the same parameters? (remember `-f` - enter exactly the parameters mentioned)

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr

Comment: If you can't start Solr manually, that's the part you'll have to fix - it won't help trying to start it as a service if Solr refuses to start at all. Fix that first, then move on to installing it as a service.

Comment: I tried starting it manually and i was successfully able to start. But when installed it as a service using nssm tool. it give me the same error message. I have added JAVA_HOME system environment variable but it didn't resolve the issue. is there any other way to debug it?

Comment: The path to your JAVA_HOME is probably incorrect, double check it. This is usually the issue...

Comment: For me solr was running, and it is currently paused(I checked after a long time) can java update possibly mess JAVA_HOME for solr?

Comment: Yes Java home was set to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171 and java was updated to 191

Answer (score 4):

I was also running with same problem. Solr service was installed successfully.
Then it got paused and tried resuming but it throws an alert to check with administrator.
I checked Java version and Java-Home path both were correct. Then I reinstall the service but again it got into same situation. Later I found out on article which say to use:

```
start -f -p 8983
```

to use in argument while installation and it did the trick now it is working fine.
So basically when you run commnad

```
nssm install <solrSerivceName>
```

it prompt for NSSM service installer

[image]

It installed solr service and solr service run well now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run Solr manually from Solr installation directory and it is failing when you start it as a service. This could be the reason.

From the NSSM download page (https://nssm.cc/download), they acknowledge the issue with Windows 10 Creators Update and offer a solution:

"2017-04-26: Users of Windows 10 Creators Update should use [prelease build 2.2.4-101](https://nssm.cc/ci/nssm-2.24-101-g897c7ad.zip) to avoid an issue with services failing to start. If for some reason you cannot use that build you can also set AppNoConsole=1 in the registry, noting that applications which expect a console window may behave unexpectedly."

Answer (score 0):

I tried  'solr.cmd start' but still the services wouldn't run. After I tried 'solr.cmd stop -all' this seemed to allow the windows service to start.